# Creating Owlready2 properties dynamically

Tags: rdf, ontology, rdflib, knowledge-graph, owlready

I am in need of creating an ontology dynamically.

for **classes** I am creating them using below method.

```
with onto:
    NewClass = types.new_class(class_name, tuple(SuperClasses))
```

But for creating **properties**(object/data etc..) I am unable to find a way to create them dynamically. Right now what I can do is :

```
with onto:
    class has_grouping(Bacterium >> Grouping):
    pass
```

where "has_grouping" is the property name. I wish to be able to create the property where the property name can be induced from a variable.

Answer (score 1):

OWL properties are actually “classes of relationship”. Properties are created
by defining a class that inherits from DataProperty, ObjectProperty,
or AnnotationProperty. In addition, the classes FunctionalProperty,
InverseFunctionalProperty, TransitiveProperty, SymmetricProperty,
AsymmetricProperty, ReflexiveProperty, and IrreflexiveProperty can
be used as additional superclasses (using multiple inheritance) in order to
create functional, inverse functional, transitive, and other properties.

Hence you can create a property dynamically in a similar manner of that of classes.

```
with onto:
    NewProperty= types.new_class(property_name, (ObjectProperty, FunctionalProperty))
```

Comment: do you know how can Domain and Range be set using the above code ??

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer posted by @Zenmate, here is a solution that includes assignment of domain and range.

```
with onto:
    prop = types.new_class(property_name, (ObjectProperty, FunctionalProperty))
    prop.domain = [domain]
    prop.range = [range]
```